# Which characters smoke in Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter

There are very few wizards or witches in *Harry Potter* who smoke. The only one I'm aware of is Mundungus Fletcher.

Is there anyone else who smokes?

Comment: Fletcher is more muggle than wizard..

Comment: "Of course, Vernon Dursley does as well" ? could you remind me? I don't remember seeing him smoke

Comment: Doris Crockford smokes a pipe if I’m not mistaken. I seem to recall several other unnamed witches and wizards in the Leaky Cauldron being described as smoking, but can’t be bothered to look it up right now (couch too comfy).

Comment: @Au101 Weird. you're right! I seemed to have remembered Vernon Dursley smoking a cigar, but I  must be confused with a fanfic.

Comment: To clarify: are you asking about smokers in the HP series in general, or in the wizarding world specifically? (I ask because the answer below includes some Muggles, such as Dudley Dursley, but in the original version of your question you seemed to be excluding Muggles from consideration.)

Comment: @Randal'Thor That is correct, I changed the scope of the question.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

- **An elderly Witch.**

  > For a famous place, it was very dark and shabby. A few old women were sitting in a corner, drinking tiny glasses of sherry. One of them was smoking a long pipe. - HPPS
- **Dudley (and his friends)**

  > Harry knew perfectly well that Dudley had not been to tea anywhere; he and his gang spent every evening vandalising the play park, smoking on street corners and throwing stones at passing cars and children. - HPOP
- **Professor Grubbly-Plank**

  > Professor Grubbly-Plank appeared at Professor McGonagall’s shoulder, smoking a pipe and holding a copy of the Daily Prophet. - HPOP
- **Mundungus Fletcher**

  > Mundungus fumbled nervously in his pockets, still staring at Harry, and pulled out a grimy black pipe. He stuck it in his mouth, ignited the end of it with his wand and took a deep pull on it. Great billowing clouds of greenish smoke obscured him within seconds. - HPOP
- **Several elderly warlocks**

  > Loud singing accompanied by what sounded like mandolins issued from a distant corner; a haze of pipe smoke hung over several elderly warlocks deep in conversation, and a number of house-elves were negotiating their way squeakily through the forest of knees, obscured by the heavy silver platters of food they were bearing, so that they looked like little roving tables. - HPHBP
- **Wizard waiters (on their break)**

  > A host of white-robed waiters had arrived an hour earlier, along with a golden-jacketed band, and all of these wizards were currently sitting a short distance away under a tree; Harry could see a blue haze of pipe smoke issuing from the spot. - HPDH

---

We also see a few more smokers in the films

- **Leaky Cauldron extras (from Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone)**

  [image]
- **Gnarlak (from Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them)**
- This concept art piece by Dermot Power shows the ghost [**Patrick Delaney-Podmore**](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Patrick_Delaney-Podmore) smoking a cigar. It was unused in Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, presumably because most of the ghost subplot was removed.

  [image]

Comment: I'm assuming a text search with words `pipe` & `smoking, smoke` ?

Comment: @atayenel - It was a shade more complicated than that, but yes, that was the foundation for the textual analysis part of the answer. I also spent some time watching the films, reading interviews by JKR about her own smoking (to see if she mentioned any characters) and reviewing various concept-art websites.